# Searching through a multimap with a pair for a key

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, multimap

I have a multimap that has the structure

```
multimap< pair<int,int>, bool >
```

I have data inserted into and it looks like this

```
I is [0] Int is [5] Bool is [0]
I is [0] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [0] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [1] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [1] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [1] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [2] Int is [5] Bool is [0]
I is [2] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
I is [2] Int is [100] Bool is [0]
```

I need to be able to have an iterator for the map to jump to the next **I** without iterating through the other **I**'s.

For example, I want to only add **Ints** that don't have the same **I** value. So it could go

> add 5 + 100 + 5

Since these would be the first values with different **I's**. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Consider to change your data definition to `std::map<int,std::multimap<int,bool>>`. That way your task would be trivial

Answer (score 0):

Well - you might use map [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/lower_bound) function - you need to apply to it "next" main key - see:

```
auto next_key(int key_first)
{
    return std::make_pair(key_first + 1, std::numeric_limits<int>::min());
}
```

So next key-pair to search is `(first + 1, INT_MIN)`.

So, the loop:

```
for (auto i = data.begin(); 
          i != data.end(); 
          i = data.lower_bound(next_key(i->first.first)))
{
    std::cout << i->first.second << std::endl;
}
```

For this data:

```
std::multimap< std::pair<int,int>, bool > data = {
    {{0,5},false},
    {{0,100},false},
    {{0,100},false},
    {{1,100},false},
    {{1,100},false},
    {{1,100},false},
    {{2,5},false},
    {{2,100},false},
    {{2,100},false}
};
```

You get:

```
5
100
5
```